# How to embed a 3D object on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fbx 3D object that I can open in windows using Mixed Reality Viewer. Is there a way to embed this in a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

`three.js` is useful in that context . https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx.html